# Skip over screens

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am working on a project for my programming class that requires us to create a login screen, a screen where the user inputs their birthday and some other information, and a blank screen (more will be done later but for the moment it's just a blank screen). When I start up my app and correctly put in the login information it skips over the second screen and goes straight to the blank one, I am unsure of why it does this. This is the code for the login screen MainActivity:

```
public enum LoginSuccess {
    login(1),
    password(2),
    success(0);

    private int intValue;

    LoginSuccess(int value){
        intValue = value;
    }

    public int getIntValue(){
        return intValue;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView txtLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idLoginText);
    final TextView txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idPassword);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toastError = null;

            switch(CheckLogin(txtLogin.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                case login:
                    toastError.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.errMessageLogin), toastError.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txtLogin.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case password:
                    toastError.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.errMessagePassword), toastError.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txtPassword.requestFocus();
                    break;
                default:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainClassList.class));


            }
        }
    });
}


LoginSuccess CheckLogin(String txtLogin, String txtPassword){
    String holdLogin = "Codie";
    String holdPassword = "password";

    if (!holdLogin.equals(txtLogin)){
        return LoginSuccess.login;
    }

    if (!holdPassword.equals(txtPassword)){
        return LoginSuccess.password;
    }

    return LoginSuccess.success;

}
}
```

This is the code for the second screen MainClassList:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_class_list);
       final Switch swDegreeCert = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.swDegreeCert);
       final Spinner spnDegree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnDegree);
       final Spinner spnCertificate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCertificate);
       final TextView txtCertificate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCertificate);
       final TextView txtDegree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDegree);
       final Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    final EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);
    final EditText lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLastName);
    final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

    final Spinner spMonth = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMonth);
    final EditText txtDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDay);
    final EditText txtYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtYear);

    firstName.requestFocus();

    swDegreeCert.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                spnDegree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtDegree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spnCertificate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtCertificate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                spnDegree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtDegree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spnCertificate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtCertificate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkData()){
                String doBirth = "";
                doBirth = spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString() + "/" + txtDay.getText().toString() + "/" + txtYear.getText().toString();

                // old way
                // startActivity(new Intent(MainClassList.this, ChooseClass.class);

                //new way
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MainClassList.this, ChooseClass.class);
                nextScreen.putExtra("FirstName", firstName.getText().toString());
                nextScreen.putExtra("LastName", lastName.getText().toString());
                nextScreen.putExtra("Phone", phone.getText().toString());
                nextScreen.putExtra("BirthDate", doBirth);

                if (spnDegree.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    nextScreen.putExtra("isDegreeCert", "Degree");
                    nextScreen.putExtra("degreeCert", spnDegree.getSelectedItem().toString());

                } else {
                    nextScreen.putExtra("isDegreeCert", "Certificate");
                    nextScreen.putExtra("degreeCert", spnCertificate.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
                //Start Activity
                startActivity(nextScreen);

            }
        }
    });
}



private boolean checkData(){
    final EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);
    final EditText lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLastName);
    final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    final EditText txtDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDay);
    final EditText txtYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtYear);


    if(firstName.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        //error
        firstName.setError("Invalid First Name");
        firstName.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if(lastName.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        lastName.setError("Invalid Last Name");
        lastName.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if(phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        phone.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
        phone.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if(txtDay.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        txtDay.setError("Invalid Date Selection");
        txtDay.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if(txtYear.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        txtYear.setError("Invalid Date Selection");
        txtYear.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}
}
```

The third class ChooseClass does not have any significant code. To reiterate, the app goes from MainActivity straight to ChooseClass and I have no idea why. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainClassList" />
    <activity android:name=".ChooseClass"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: avoid enums they comsume alot of memory and add your manifest here.

Comment: put a log under `btnNext` click listener just to see if it being called automatically somehow.

Comment: Manifest added to original post

Comment: what about the log did you try?

Comment: I added a log at btnNext and when I ran the app the logcat just kept going, not sure what that means, tried it in debug mode as well and it did the same thing

Comment: Are you using androidx dependencies..those are causing plently of such problems these days. and I am assuming you know how to find the data you are looking for in your log right??

Comment: I am actually using bluestacks as my system was not compatible with the built in emulators in studio, and I'm fairly inept when it comes to this as I've really only been learning over the last few months with frequent help. I thought the logcat was supposed to stop wherever you placed the log in your code?

Comment: no thats not how it works. I will tell you more about logs later for now paste Log.i("btnNext","next button is autocalled"); and in your log search for btnNext. If you see it its being called somehow . I suggest you run the app on a real device and see.